# RazorGenerator in MVC to compile Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC project where the view engine is Umbraco. But my views are not compiled and hence I have added Razorgenerator. I need to manually edit my cshtml page properties and update Custom Tool as "RazorGenerator". Is there a way that I can automatically apply this to all my existing views and the views which will be created later ? Any help is appreciated.

Note: Razorgenerator is not used as View Engine here !!

Comment: Have you tried `Enable-RazorGenerator`?

Comment: This would enable razor view engine. But my view engine is umbraco.